# How can I log in to Ubuntu using a USB serial port?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, console, serial-port, rs232

How can I enable remote terminal log in into [Ubuntu 9.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_9.10_.28Karmic_Koala.29) (Karmic Koala) using a USB serial port?

I created device */dev/ttyUSB0*, and I want to allow logins using [HyperTerminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperACCESS).

I found some resources, but they are related to real hardware RS-232 ports. I can't find any information about a USB converter.

So far I have established connection between that USB-serial port and my laptop.  I can send text to the port (*cp sometext.txt /dev/ttyUSB0*) and read it using HyperTerminal.

What do I need to do to enable logins on this port?

Answer (score 3):

See the [Ubuntu Serial Console HowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SerialConsoleHowto).  You'll need to adapt it for your hardware -- instead of ***ttyS0***, which is the first hardware serial port, you'll need to use ***ttyUSB0***.  An example of this is below.

---

At minimum, you need to configure *upstart* to start a *getty* on that port.

1. Create `/etc/init/ttyUSB0.conf` and paste the following into it:

   ```
   # ttyUSB0 - getty on USB serial port
   #
   # This service maintains a getty on ttyUSB0 from the point the system is
   # started until it is shut down again.

   start on stopped rc RUNLEVEL=[2345]
   stop on runlevel [!2345]

   respawn
   exec /sbin/getty -L 115200 ttyUSB0 vt102
   ```
2. Start the getty:

   ```
   sudo start ttyUSB0
   ```

Older Ubuntu versions and distributions that don't use *upstart* do this by adding a line in */etc/inittab*.

This doesn't consider changes to the bootloader configuration to allow Grub to talk to the serial port; refer to the [HowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SerialConsoleHowto) for details.  I'm not sure if Grub can talk to a USB serial port or if that's limited to hardware ports.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the above answers *may* work if your distribution is still using
`upstart` as the init daemon. This is relatively rare these days however. For
most modern systems using `systemd` as the init system, you can easily spawn a
login prompt over a USB serial port as follows:

```
sudo systemctl start serial-getty@ttyUSB0.service
```

(Adjust @ttyUSB0 to whatever port you are using ttyS0, ttyUSB1, etc)

Then double check baud-rate etc using `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0` before logging in
using your preferred serial terminal client.

Answer (score 0):

Better approach in Ubuntu 12.04:

```
start on (tty-device-added ttyUSB0)
stop on (runlevel [!2345] or tty-device-removed ttyUSB0)

respawn
exec /sbin/getty -L 115200 ttyUSB0 vt102
```

- starting getty when hot plugging in ttyUSB0
- stop getty when hot plugging out ttyUSB0

Comment: Where should this go? Typed into a terminal window? In some Bash script?

Comment: In file `/etc/init/ttyUSB0.conf`?

Comment: Yes, `/etc/init/ttyUSB0.conf`